# Informatica relational connection password change

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

Yesterday I had installed Informatica 9.1.0 and after that I was able to run Informatica workflow successfully. Today I have reset the password of one relational connection using sql developer-->connections(Right Click)-->Reset Password.

I have not updated this password anywhere else after resetting and I **have also not** updated this password in **workflow manager** under **connections** and when I ran the workflow it **completed successfully**. If I have not updated this password in workflow manager then **from where** Informatica is taking this new password ?

Comment: have you changed password for correct user (the user you are using in informatica connection)? Can you use some other client like sqlplus to confirm the user/pass? And yes, it shouldnt happen - informatica will fail if you change pass for the user.

Comment: You are right Koushik and I have tried the same using sqlplus also as you suggested and I didn’t update the password anywhere else at Informatica end but still its not failing the session.I am doing only and only password change task and not doing any other task  than this. I am still not sure from where its taking this new password.